# How can I mount an external drive with the permission to execute programs from it?

Tags: mount, ext4, executable

I wanna mount my USB HDD formated as EXT4 to let say /home/user/exe where there will be executable files.
when I mounted my HDD there it mounts fine but I can't run any executable file from there I added the mount point to my path but every time I run an executable it always send the same error output, example :

```
$ adb
```

the output is:

```
$ /home/user/exe/android-sdks/platform-tools/adb : no such file or directory.
```

My question is why is this happening and how can I fix it?

additionnal info

mount line in /etc/fstab

```
UUID=e5fefc59-19a3-47a1-a3f4-844880ccdfcf   /home/lord-ralf-adolf/oldhome   ext4    defaults    0   2
```

Comment: how do you mount it? please show your fstab or command line..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not related to mounting points or permissions.

You need to install `ia32` library because Linux 64-bit `adt` bundle comes with a 32 bit `adb`.

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
```

Comment: But adb executable runs normally when I copy it to my bin folder the libs are installed on my PC I know I need them :-) ,I know it's a permission thing because the mount poor spears on my home folder with a lock sign on it and I have no rights to delete or add files when I am not  running nautilus as root

Comment: you should add those to your question to clarify